# Android - Starting a thread from a widget View class

Tags: android, android-widget

So I have a View:

```
public class RadialMenuWidget extends View
```

from where I want to start a thread like I do from an activity

```
String urlInput = "http://myserver.com/"+mynewfile;
DownloaderThread downloaderThread = new DownloaderThread(UpdateActivity, urlInput);
downloaderThread.start();
```

but I get the message "Expression expected" on this line "DownloaderThread(UpdateActivity,... " more specifically on the activity name (UpdateActivity) even though I imported the activity inside the Widget.

What can I do to avoid this while still being able to call the thread.

The idea is, I use the RadialMenuWidget, and inside the RadialMenuWidget class I test to see which menu button was pressed and based on that, I decide what to do next. Calling other intents works just fine, but now I want to start to download a file using a separate thread (that I can call from a regular activity's onButtonClick)

**EDIT**
So my radialMenu has this structure:

```
public class RadialMenuWidget extends View {
...
   public interface RadialMenuEntry {
   ...
   }
   public RadialMenuWidget(Context context) {
   ...
   }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    ...
        if (state == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        ...
          if (menuEntries.get(i).getName() == "Update now") {
               String urlInput = "http://myhost.com/"+mynewfile;
               DownloaderThread downloaderThread = new DownloaderThread(this.UpdateActivity, urlInput);
               downloaderThread.start();
          }
        }
...
```

And the DownloadThread class looks like this:

```
public class DownloaderThread  extends Thread {

 public DownloaderThread(UpdateActivity inParentActivity, String inUrl)
    {
        downloadUrl = "";
        if(inUrl != null)
        {
            downloadUrl = inUrl;
        }
        parentActivity = inParentActivity;
    }

 @Override
    public void run()
    {
     // does the download
    }
...
}
```

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: What's signature of "DownloaderThread".  `UpdateActivity` is a name and not a reference.

Comment: I added some more code (EDITED) so you'll have a better view. Please explain what should I do and why. Thank you

Comment: Indeed, I used to call the DownloaderThread from UpdateActivity, but now I want to add the RadialMenuWidget in this activity and call the downloader from it's menu items click (that is located inside the RadialMenuWidget class...

Comment: It would be better to have the Thread in the Activity and use a callback like "onClick" to start it.

Comment: Like I said, this is the way it is done right now (onclick inside the activity), but I want to call it from the click on the menu (RadialMenuWidget) https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android because I started to change the project to use the widget and it does not look cool to jump from using the radialmenu to an empty activity with a button inside

Comment: So I want to avoid showing an empty activity showing a button that says "Download". I would prefere to show a radial menu with 2 buttons on it "Download" and "Cancel". And my previous activity also uses the widget so it would be appropriate to continue using a menu similar to the previous one

Comment: The actual code of the RadialMenuWidget can be found here: https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Library-Source/blob/master/Radial%20Menu/src/com/touchmenotapps/widget/radialmenu/menu/v1/RadialMenuWidget.java

Answer (score 0):

My solution in the end was to mimic a 2 button radial menu using images. I used the images as backgrounds for a button, placed them in a linear layout, used 9-patch images and got to call the thread onClick like before. So I avoided having to deal with radialMenuWidget in this view. 
So question is over now. 
I was hoping for a java solution to this problem since I am a newbie and eager to learn anything Android, but this is it, I will manage with my (ugly) solution.